# Print PDF in Firefox with Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, pdf, printing

I'm building an application running in Firefox on a terminal in a warehouse. This application needs to print PDFs.

I found a lot of questions and answers about printing PDF from Javascript, but I can't get it to work.

This is my current code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document.body).append('<IFRAME id="pdfLabel" ... >');
    $('iframe#pdfLabel').attr('src', 'testlabel.pdf');

    $('iframe#pdfLabel').load(function() {
        document.getElementById('pdfLabel').focus();
        document.getElementById('pdfLabel').contentWindow.print();
    });
});
```

With a regular html page in the iFrame, this code works flawlessly. With PDF, the pdf is displayed in the iFrame, but not printed. I tried printing with the Firefox built in PDF renderer and with embedded Adobe acrobat reader. I also tried

```
document.getElementById('pdfLabel').print();
```

But that throws 
`TypeError: window.frames.pdfLabel.print is not a function`

Comment: Since you're using the `id` selector, you don't need `iframe` at the beginning of the selector...just use `$("#pdfLabel")`. Can you put a `console.log('here');` in the `.load` function? I know you said it loads, but just to make sure your `.load` code is running. Also, you might want to set the `src` attribute _after_ binding the `.load` event

Comment: give some time for pdf to load. possibly using setTimeout

Comment: @Ian `.load` is running, I checked. I set the `src` attribute after binding the load event, but it doesn't help.
@bighostkim Tried it, didn't help. Thank you both for the suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

. . Sadly, the PDF.js version shipped with Firefox 19 doesn't support built-in JavaScript to self-print the document and it also doesn't allow you to access anything inside the PDF window (including the print method).

. . [They are aware of the problem](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=839627) and the fix is planned to ship with version 21 of Firefox.

Comment: The bug you link to is marked as fixed, however, you still cannot print in Firefox (as of v39) with javascript, at least to my knowledge.

Comment: @Lynda, have you tried both options (self-printing with JavaScript and self.print() JS snippet?). I didn't have the need to check PDFs and self-printing lately, but they really shipped the patch. Maybe someone should reopen the issue or open a new one.

Comment: [They know about it](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/5397). That link is just one example of many pages I found on this. The patch did ship as you said, however, from what I have read that didn't solve all of the problems.